# Why ContentAssets Deployment creating "No Network Named" issue?

Tags: lightning-community, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to migrate community configurations from one scratch orgs to another. Everything works fine except ContentAsset.

I am getting the following error:-

```
PS E:\Projects\xxxxx-build test> sfdx force:source:push -u xxxxxBuild
PROJECT PATH                                                
ERROR──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\contentassets\xxxxxkeyvisual.asset  ContentAsset xxxxxkeyvisual [03S1X00000007Zx] - No Network named [xxxxx_partner] (0:0)
force-app\main\default\contentassets\xxxxxkeyvisual.asset  This record isn't in the target org: xxxxx_partner. (0:0)
force-app\main\default\contentassets\logoxxxxx.asset      ContentAsset logoxxxxx [03S1X00000007Zy] - No Network named [xxxxx_partner] (0:0)
force-app\main\default\contentassets\logoxxxxx.asset      This record isn't in the target org: xxxxx_partner. (0:0)
ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed.
```

I checked my directory and found that **xxxxx_partner** network is already available there.

If anyone have idea deploying community please suggest the solution. I am attaching a screenshot of the directory structure.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. You need to first create a community in target org with same name and url.

2.Then rename it to something else and rename it back to the original community name.

And then deploy the code.
Step 2 is needed because of a issue with network naming convention.

If you will check the network xml file the network name has a __c sufix while when you create the community for the first time this sufix is not there.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Got this error and resolved my self by performing below steps
Error Message: *Error *"Portal Name"* The value for urlPathPrefix in ExperienceBundle isn't valid. Check the value and try again*

Solution:

1. Enable Experience Workspace on target sandbox.
2. Add a site with the same name and url under All Sites.
3. Target Experiences folder and *"Portal Name"*.site-meta.xml file to change urlPathPrefix value to s.
   something like this. [image]